# SSAS Processing tasks Optimization

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssas, sql-server-2005-express, measures

I have 10 Dimensions and 10 MeasureGroups

I tried to process a particular MeasureGroup(say MeasureGroup-1) and associated dimensions(Which i saw in a window while > Right click on cube > newQuery > MDX >Selected MeasureGroup-1 in dropdown list) in a Single Processing Task-1(Say)  in "Process Full" Mode.. But what is see in Impact analysis is other MeasureGroups/Partitons are also affected.

I also tried to Process Measuregroups in  parallel ie 1st i'm processing all the dimensions followed by measuregroups(measures Groups in parallel Using different Processing task each for each measureGroup).

```
                           Dimensions

             MEASUREGROUP-1         MEASUREGROUP-2
```

Please suggest is this correct or wrong..

I'm beginner in SSAS.. Please Suggest how to optimize..

Answer (score 0):

When you process a dimension using Process Full, all measure groups and partitions that use those dimensions become unprocessed.

To avoid this, only process your dimensions as Process Update.

I would also as a rule recommend separating your dimension process from your measure group / partition processing for future maintainability.

Comment: Thnx for the response kyle !! If i process all the dimension as process update.. what happens to measure groups.. I mean do i need to process them in process update or process full.

Comment: They don't have a Process Update for measure groups, you just want Process Default most of the time. If you only have one partition in your measure group, this becomes a Process Full.